# 4-20mA with 12V sensors using ADS1115 ADCs

Tags: adc, ground, 4-20ma

I am currently designing a 4-20mA current loop with external sensors which work at 12V DC. I saw a differential application on the datasheet of the [ADS1115 ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf), but the simple shunt resistor I believe would be OK in my situation.  I would like your opinion on the GND side of the shunt resistors, is a 100 ohm (R25) resistor enough?

On a MAX31865ATP there is an analog ground for the analog part of the [schematic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hallard/MAX31865-Breakout/master/MAX31865-sch.png).

Should I also isolate my 4-20mA or doesn't it matter, because I only need to measure the current passing through the known shunt resistors?

[image: keep in mind that (R21 to R24) are the same part]

**keep in mind that (R21 to R24) are the same part

Also, is my assumption of the 10 ohm shunt good, providing that the ADC reads from -0.3V to 0.3V? Or should I put a bigger resistor and extend to the input limits of my ADC?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add more details. First of all, what do you mean with "ADC reads from -0.3V to 0.3V"? Can you provide some details on how this sensor is working? Why do you think that a common 100 Ohms resistor (R25) is necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the observation, the adc  reads from GND - 0,3 to VCC + 0,3 . So I would definitely increase the shunt resistor value.  I just added a 100Ohm resistor to the GND I really don't know why, I was affected by the analog ground of the max31865. I think that the adc works like a volt meter and it needs the "negative lead", should I just put the commons directly on the ground?

Comment: Yes, you should put the commons directly to GND. Use 240 Ohms resistors to make use of the full input range of the ADC.